# Mixing audio in a microprocessor

Tags: microcontroller, audio, embedded

I need to do a project where I mix up to 8 to 10 audio channels together to play through a speaker. This needs to be done on a low cost microcontroller such as an ARM cortex M0 and I am thinking about how to do it.

The audio will be placed in an SPI FLASH memory chip in raw mono format (bit depth should 12-16).

The only way I can see to do it is to add the samples together - but for this I need a much higher dynamic range than 16 bits. So I think I would need a 24 bit DAC.

Is there anything else I am missing? Any other ways to mix audio or to do it without an expensive DAC? Is it even achievable?

Comment: Add the samples together .. and then divide by the number of samples you've added together.

Comment: Mixing is addition. If the inputs are 12 bit depth you can add 16 channels without exceeding 16 bit output. (Fading is multiplication; then you need to round (crude) or add dither and round (hi-fi) back to 16 bits before mixing.

Comment: If you value your time just get an 8 channel audio mixing console.

Comment: Is there a need to do it digitally?

Comment: Sample rate and real time requirements shouldn't be overlooked (e.g. can you precompute the audio output?). Audio DACs are fairly cheap (82 cents a piece for 10 24 bit stereo DACs - is that too expensive?)

Comment: The sampling rate will be 16khz, so hopefully there will be enough time to do the calculations. Will need to do the maths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding 8 samples together only requires 3 extra bits.

After adding the samples together to get the mixed signal, divide by the number of samples.  That is always guaranteed to fit into the original word width, although the sum needs to be wider.  Specifically, the accumulator needs Log<sub>2</sub>(samples) more bits than each of the samples.  Note that dividing by 2<sup>N</sup> is just shifting right by N bits.  To get the average of 8 samples, add them up, then shift the result right 3 bits.

This kind of arithmetic is what DSPs are intended for.  They have accumulators you can add into that are wider than regular data words.  They also generally can shift the result a arbitrary number of bits in a single instruction cycle.

You said your original samples might be only 12 bits.  In that case, you can add up to 16 of them without overflowing a 16 bit word.  That might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: its not as bad as I thought then. I can just add the samples together into a 16 bit int then (without shifting) or if I want to be very cheap, shift right by 3 and then I can use a 12 bit DAC. How will it sound though? Will there be an distortion/artifacts from the mixing? Thanks for your answer...

Comment: @gcb: It will sound fine.

Comment: Add then shift, not vice-versa, if you want to preserve accuracy.

Comment: @Nick: Yes.  I just re-read my answer, and I think it's quite clear that the divide (which can be realized by a shift in some cases) is supposed to be on the sum.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yes, I was responding to gcb's comment "or if I want to be very cheap, shift right by three".